# Using d-i partman recipe strings?

Tags: partition, system-installation, debian-installer, preseed, partition-table

I want to automatically partition all of my workstations in the same way:

- First partition is a bootable 1GB ext4 /boot partition
- Second partition is a 2GB swap partition
- Third partition is an ext4 / partition that takes up whatever is left
- All partitions should be formatted

I think adding this to my preseed.cfg will accomplish what I want:

```
d-i partman-auto/workstation_recipe string \
    root :: \
        1024 1023 1024 ext4 \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ /boot } \
        . \
        2048 2047 2048 linux-swap \
            $primary{ } \
            method{ swap } format{ } \
        . \
        17408 100000000000 -1 ext4 \
            $primary{ } \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ / } \
        .
```

This is based on [this blog](http://www.bishnet.net/tim/blog/2015/01/29/understanding-partman-autoexpert_recipe/). Will this do what I want, and is there anything else I need to add to my preseed.cfg to make it accept these instructions without user intervention? I have never used partman recipes before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured this out after spending days scouring the internet for *any* shred of information about partman - it is not very well-documented at all. Here's the config I used:

```
# This automatically creates a standard unencrypted partitioning scheme.
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select unencrypted-install
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
        unencrypted-install :: \
                1024 1024 1024 ext4 \
                        $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
                        method{ format } format{ } \
                        use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                        mountpoint{ /boot } \
                . \
                2048 2048 2048 linux-swap \
                        $primary{ } \
                        method{ swap } format{ } \
                . \
                17408 100000000000 -1 ext4 \
                        $primary{ } \
                        method{ format } format{ } \
                        use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                        mountpoint{ / } \
                .
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Just drop that in your preseed and you should be good to go. Line by line:

- Use disk /dev/sda
- Do a regular install (not encrypted or LVM)
- Remove any existing LVM without prompting
- Remove any existing RAID setup without prompting
- Confirm that this is what you want
- Confirm again
- Select the "unencrypted-install" recipe, which is specified below
- This is a single logical line that specifies the entire recipe, one partition at a time. It creates the partition table exactly as I specified in the question.
- Confirm again
- Allow partman to write new labels
- Finish the process
- Confirm again
- Confirm again

And there you go, works perfect.

Comment: Well done for posting what you found.  The paucity of info and lack of exhaustive directory for all the preseed directives is a travesty of modern computing.  I dread to think of `$myTimeWasted*$numEngineers`.

Comment: Can you explain why did you choose 17408 for the minimum size? It seems a number that you calculated carefully ... this is what I'm trying to understand .. if you are about to make minimum of 17GB, why not go with 17000 ? How did you get that 17408 ?

Comment: @MaXi32 OP is consistently using power of two sizing. First partition is 1GiB second is 2GiB and third at least 17GiB

Comment: What is the number of `n` that you are getting `17,408`? The first is correct where `2^n = (2^10) =1024`, The second one is also correct `2^11 = 2048`,  The third is not in the chart of power 2 sizings, the minimum size would be `2^14` which is equal to `16,384`. So `17,408` is not in that range. If you pick `2^15` it is equal to `32,768` . So, I guess he picked a random number without thinking. Still does not answer my question.

Comment: Actually, I just got the answer myself, The number he picked is actually just a random number where most people will do this without reason. When he put `-1` in the last partition (the third argument), it is already assumed that the last partition would take the rest of the available space so this line: `17408 100000000000 -1 ext4`  where the number `17408` and `100000000000` are not important to have bigger value.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. 
I had a similar problem. When I read your solution I realised that my expert_recipe string starts with `boot-root` which seems to be a variable that has to be set in line `d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root`otherwise installation fails with "No space left on device" - seen on Screen 4 during installation.

Comment: The priority number of 100 billion will probably not work on 32 bit systems.  Also it's unnecessary.  Any priority greater than the min size (17408) will accomplish the same thing, since the other partitions can't be given more space according to the recipe (min size equals max size).  (In actual fact since this partition is listed last, it will likely be set to take up the remaining space on the disk regardless of the priority, but there may be some exceptions to that rule; I've only read a *lot* of the partman auto code and not *all* of it.)

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post but I am not sure if hard coding `/dev/sda` is a good idea. Instead, I'd use something similar to

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
    USBDEV=$(list-devices usb-partition | sed "s/\(.*\)./\1/");\
    if [ ! -z "$USBDEV" ]; then \
        BOOTDEV=$(list-devices disk | grep -v "$USBDEV" | head -1);\
    else \
        BOOTDEV=$(list-devices disk | head -1);\
    fi; \
    debconf-set partman-auto/disk $BOOTDEV;\
    debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev $BOOTDEV;\
    lvremove --select all -ff -y; vgremove --select all -ff -y; pvremove ${BOOTDEV}* -ff -y
```

To make sure that the first internal drive is used as the installation medium and any possible external usb drive is excluded as the enumeration order might change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try these 3 lines (making changes as fits):

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

Comment: Hi @Tshepang, thank you for your answer. This was the start of what I needed to do. These lines will select /dev/sda for partitioning and get you ready to partition that disk. Setting up the partman recipe was a much more involved process, but I managed to do it; see my answer below.